# Python ARI playback status

Tags: python, asterisk

I am using ARI code from here:

http://techvoiper.blogspot.com/2015/08/asterisk-ari-interfacing-using-python.html

Now, what I want to do is know the status of playback if the caller hangs up while the audio has not been completed?

While the playback starts, 'PlaybackStarted' event is registered, and on completion, 'PlaybackFinished' is registered. But when the caller hangs up  while the audio has been playing, it still returns 'PlaybackFinished'.

In this case, I want the playback_status to be set into something like :
playback_status = 'partial'.

How can I achieve this?

My ChannelHangupRequest gives me:

> {u'timestamp': u'2017-01-27T10:04:17.447+0545', u'type': u'ChannelHangupRequest', u'channel': {u'accountcode': u'', u'name': u'SIP/3002-00000012', u'language': u'en', u'caller': {u'name': u'', u'number': u'3002'}, u'creationtime': u'2017-01-27T10:04:15.847+0545', u'state': u'Up', u'connected': {u'name': u'', u'number': u''}, u'dialplan': {u'priority': 2, u'exten': u'3001', u'context': u'default'}, u'id': u'1485490755.36'}, u'application': u'hello-world'}

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample of the API in the [ari-py github repository](https://github.com/asterisk/ari-py/tree/master/sample-api)

There you'll see that there is a `ChannelHangupRequest` event which has a *cause* integer attribute, you then can find the mapping definition [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Cause+Mappings)

The event should be catch using the `client.on_channel_event("ChannelHangupRequest", <callback_function>)`.

The callback_function will receive a channel object as first argument and an event dictionary as second. The `event` dictionary will have a `type` key corresponding to the event(`ChannelHangupRequest`) and a `cause` key corresponding integer value(mapping of the cause).

This way you will be able to differentiate if the playback went through or if call was hang up.